# Checking the presence of values in multiple datasets

Tags: r

I have a number of tables and all the "a" columns of the tables must have identical values for the analysis I am conducting. The actual tables are very big so I will use simplified (mock) data frames.

Let's say I have the following data:

```
A <- data.frame(a = c(3,4,5,6,7,8), b = c(4,5,6,7,8,9), c = c(5,6,7,8,9,10))

B <- data.frame(a = c(2,3,4,5,6,7), b = c(4,5,6,7,8,9), c = c(5,6,7,8,9,10))

C <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4,5,6), b = c(4,5,6,7,8,9), c = c(5,6,7,8,9,10))

D <- data.frame(a = c(4,5,6,7,8,9), b = c(4,5,6,7,8,9), c = c(5,6,7,8,9,10))
```

Now, each data frame has unidentical values in column "a"s. My goal is to delete the entire rows that contain different values as compared to all the other tables.

In order to have identical values in column "a" for all tables A, B and C, I could use the following operations:

```
A <- A[A$a %in% B$a,]
B <- B[B$a %in% A$a,]
C <- C[C$a %in% B$a,]
B <- B[B$a %in% C$a,]
A <- A[A$a %in% C$a,]
```

This is already getting very tedious as you can see. What if I throw the table D or other data frames in this mix. It's becoming almost impossible to proceed, as each table contain at least one unique value.

Answer (score 0):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
bind_rows(list(A, B, C, D), .id = "ID") %>%
 mutate(n_datasets = max(ID)) %>%
 group_by(a) %>%
 filter(n_distinct(ID) == n_datasets)

   ID        a     b     c n_datasets
   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>     
 1 1         4     5     6 4         
 2 1         5     6     7 4         
 3 1         6     7     8 4         
 4 2         4     6     7 4         
 5 2         5     7     8 4         
 6 2         6     8     9 4         
 7 3         4     7     8 4         
 8 3         5     8     9 4         
 9 3         6     9    10 4         
10 4         4     4     5 4         
11 4         5     5     6 4         
12 4         6     6     7 4
```